# Closed XML change entire row background color based on cell value

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I'm trying to color an entire row based on a cell selection(value).I want to change the color of the row just for the used range in my worksheet but not for unused cells.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWorkbook();
    }

    static void CreateWorkbook()
    {
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var ws1 = workbook.AddWorksheet("Main");
        var ws2 = workbook.AddWorksheet("ListOfOptions");

        var listOfStrings = new List<String>();
        listOfStrings.Add(" ");
        listOfStrings.Add("Edit");
        listOfStrings.Add("Delete");

        ws2.Cell(2,2).InsertData(listOfStrings);
        workbook.Worksheet(1).Column(3).SetDataValidation().List(ws2.Range("B2:B4"), true);

        var list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(new Person() { Name = "John", Age = 30, Action = " " });
        list.Add(new Person() { Name = "Mary", Age = 15, Action = " " });
        list.Add(new Person() { Name = "Luis", Age = 21, Action = " " });
        list.Add(new Person() { Name = "Henry", Age = 45, Action = " " });

        ws1.Cell(1, 1).InsertData(list.AsEnumerable());

        ws1.RangeUsed().AddConditionalFormat().WhenContains("Edit")
            .Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Yellow);
        ws1.RangeUsed().AddConditionalFormat().WhenContains("Delete")
            .Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Red);

        ws2.Hide(); 
        workbook.SaveAs("DemoWorkbook.xlsx");
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The result is this:
[See excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1VpR.png)

Comment: ClosedXML can only apply conditional formats for a cell itself.

Comment: As mentioned by Raidri, the problem is your style being applied to cells containing Edit or Delete, not to their rows. Even if you do `ws1.Rows().ForEach(r => r.AsRange().AddConditionalFormat(). WhenContains("Edit").Fill.SetBackgroundColor( XLColor.Yellow));` is still applying color only to all cells that contain those words in the used range.

Answer (score 3):

With VB.NET -

```
            Dim nonEmptyDataRows = ws.RowsUsed
            For Each dataRow In nonEmptyDataRows
                Dim cell As String = dataRow.Cell(29).Value
                If cell = "0" Then
                    dataRow.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Yellow
                ElseIf cell = "1" Then
                    dataRow.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Green
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: The question wasn't about VB.NET.